Driver syntax error when using python sql alchemy. I have driver installed
I keep getting a pyodbc error.
Here is my error:
(pyodbc.Error) ('IM012', '[IM012] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] DRIVER keyword syntax error (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')    

Here is my code:
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connection_string = (
'mssql+pyodbc://@server_name/database_name? 
driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server;Trusted_Connection=yes')
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
engine.connect()

If I check my obdc drivers using the below it shows that I have 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'.
pyodbc.drivers()

Output:
['SQL Server',
'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)',
'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)',
'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)',
'Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)',
'SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0',
'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']

Any help would be appreciated, thank you! I did some research into similar issues but was unable to find solution.

Querystring parameters are separated by &, not ;,
connection_string = (
    'mssql+pyodbc://@server_name/database_name?'
    'driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&Trusted_Connection=yes'
)

